# JavaScript Count String Without Spaces

Tags: javascript

```
GEN000 AMA000 GaT000
```

I only need to count the number of text without the spaces

Comment: What you tried so far? Are you attempting to solve this in any particular way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as an alternative approach:

```
'GEN000 AMA000 GaT000'.match(/\S/g).length;  // 18
```

However, the fastest solution should always be a single `for` loop:

```
var str = 'GEN000 AMA000 GaT000',
    count = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== ' ')
        count++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var text = "GEN000 AMA000 GaT000";
var length = text.split(" ").join("").length;

console.log(length);
```

Comment: @katspaugh This answer is not exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @katspaugh My answer is in [different place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20804609/1249581) `:)`

Comment: @VisioN, I need more coffee :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution,

```
alert(str.replace(/\s/g, "").length);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3jfL/)